# How to Automatically jump to the corresponding language of the page using WPML plugin in wordpress

Tags: plugin-wpml

I'm setting up a multi-language blog using WPML. I works well using the button to change the language. Is there any way to automatically jump according to the Browser's language?
My WPML version is 2.0.4.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more, what do you mean by visitor's language ? Browser language ? Also which version of wpml are you using ? In latest commercial version of WPML there is a settings to enable browser language detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes under, 
WPML-->Languages--->Browser language redirect.

Select one of the 3 options and hit "apply".

Comment: Yes, i choose http://www.rocwing.com?lang=en - English. Then i change browser's language to English. But when i visit my blog, it still display my native language.

Comment: There is no option to choose a language for this setting, the three options are,  1. Disable browser language redirect
  2. Redirect visitors based on browser language only if translations exist
  3. Always redirect visitors based on browser language (redirect to home page if translations are missing). Also this is a commercial plugin with a support forum, your version is out of date and very likely does not have this feature.